# How to display different dropdown options in a component depending on a given value

Tags: vue.js

I'm fairly new to Vue, and I'm looking to display different dropdown option menu's depending on a given value  to the component.

my Groceries component:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <select class="Groceries" name="">
      <option v-for="value in values" v-bind:value="value.id">{{ value }}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Groceries',
  data() {
    return {
      values: {
        fruit: ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'],
        veg: ['carrot', 'pea', 'sprout']
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And looking to call the component in another component by:

```
<Groceries val="fruit"/> 

//should display a dropdown of 'apple', 'orange', 'pear'. or:/

<Flowers val="veg"/>

//should display a dropdown of 'carrot', 'pea', 'sprout'.
```

At the moment I'm getting a dropdown of both arrays. Is this something I could achieve using props? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Groceries` component should be like :

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <select class="Groceries" name="">
      <option v-for="val in values" v-bind:value="val">{{ val }}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Groceries',
    props: ["values"],
    data() {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and call it in a parent one a follow :

```
<template>
  <div class="">
      <Groceries :values="values.fruit"/>
      <Groceries :values="values.veg"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Groceries from './Groceries.vue'
  export default {
    name: 'myapp',
    data() {
      return {
        values: {
          fruit: ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'],
          veg: ['carrot', 'pea', 'sprout']
        },
      }
    },
    components: {
      Groceries
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thats great. Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome, please approve my edit to your question

Comment: Just a quick one is there a way to change a buttons class style on click? I have <button class="initial" :class="{'is-active': activeTab === 1}" @click="activeTab = 1"type="button" name="button">VEG</button> However the initial class isn't overridden on click to .is-active?

Comment: try `:class="{is-active: activeTab === 1}"` without quotes '' if that doesn't work try to post another question